# Webservice client to connect SugarCRM web service from PhoneGap

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

I have SugarCRM Web services in the below link.
http://www.sugarcrm.besplatform.com/soap.php?wsdl

Using web services, I wanted to login and list Leads Management Details through SugarCRM Web Services. I am not able to access SugarCRM web services because of "cross - domain security" issue and "same origin" issue.

I have tried using JSONP , but could not succeed.

I am new to jquery and jsonp. Some one could help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

using ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("inside ajax");
        var username = "admin";
        var password = "admin";
        $.ajax({
              url: "www.sugarcrm.besplatform.com/soap.php/login",
              data: "{'user_name':'" + username + "','password':'" + password + "'}",
              dataType: "json",
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              success: function(data) {
                    if (data == null) { 
                          alert( "nothing."); 
                    }
                    else {
                          alert(data);
                    }
              },
              error: function(e){
                alert("failure : "+e);
              }
        });
```

using jsonp:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var url = "http://www.sugarcrm.besplatform.com/soap.php/login?user_name=admin&password=admin";
        jQuery.getJSON(url+"&callback=?", function(data) {
            alert("Success" + data.id);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send the password MD5 encrypted to Sugar. Also there's a REST WS available at "../service/v2/rest.php" that you could use instead of the SOAP interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 6.5.11 this is fixed. If you use "jsoncallback" and then the name it works. Take a look at the file service/core/REST/SugarRestJSON.php to see what changed and patch older versions of sugar